# How can I check if the node is using cuda at run-time?

Tags: ros, cuda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have successfully built autoware.ai from source with CUDA enabled. The rosbag demo also runs properly.
My question is: will the node like `lidar_euclidean_cluster_detect` automatically utilize gpu so long as it compiled with cuda? Is there any way to check whether the node is using gpu at run-time? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370142/how-can-i-check-if-the-node-is-using-cuda-at-run-time?/) by [runtao](https://answers.ros.org/users/60564/runtao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2021-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can run `nvidia-smi` in your terminal and see what processes are using your gpu. Combine this with watch and you can get pseudo real-time resource usage. `watch -n 1 nvidia-smi`

---

Originally posted by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) with karma: 459 on 2021-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RevatiNaik](https://answers.ros.org/users/69532/revatinaik/) on 2021-02-11**:
To confirm if your docker is compatible with GPU, run `nvidia-docker run nvidia/cuda:10.0-base nvidia-smi`.

Do this check only if you are using a docker to run your application.